# Which animation/view is used for Recent apps/History in android 5.0(Lollipop)?

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to do animation like it is there in Recent App section in Android 5.0.
Like shown in the image below. Any hint or link or even the Animation type used here would be helpful.

[image: Animation/UI type?]

Comment: What have you tried? You should try to accomplish this yourself before asking then post what you have asking for help. Please read the rules!

Comment: @BenjaminPaul to try something, one must know where to start from? Would you please throw some light on animation type used here?

Comment: @Ankit How am I meant to provide a guess at the animation used in a still picture and no description? Wake up.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul seriously? Now a days if somebody dont know anything asked in the question they downvote it. I never downvoted any question on SO. And SO is google for Developers We dont google it we StackOverflow it.
If OP asked to give the code for the animation, it would have better to ask him/her to write it itself. But getting or giving a clue isnt bad anyway.
Happy Downvoting :)

BTW you can see people started upvoting it :P

Comment: @Ankit .. Notice the flood of answers to this awesome question.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Are you serious? Go and ask a simple question like how to handle a click event, and you will see 10s of answers in 1 min and no down votes. Cause everybody knows the answers. Every tough question has very less number of answers. It happens Sir. Are you on drugs? btw this is not the question by me, I just edited it and made a comment.

Comment: I searched a lot on internet for an answer of this  question! Did You find it?

Comment: @user3667911 Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 12):

Take a look here: https://github.com/vikramkakkar/DeckView 
There is also an example here. You can also find about `RecentsView` here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/59701b9ba5c453e327bc0e6873a9f6ff87a10391/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents/views/RecentsView.java

Comment: I had been working on another library project which is done & hosted now. So, I have some time to see if `DeckView` can be backported. A sample app on the play store would be nice too. The Github page does not have any screenshots. If you need to see what `DeckView` looks like, go here: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29444899/2558882)

Comment: there's no backward compatibility for DeckView unfortunately, it can only be applied on API 21 or higher

Answer (score 3):

I have never done this, but I can point you in the right direction to use [StackView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html). It was added in API level 11 (Android 3.0)

I have found some examples

- http://www.broculos.net/2011/12/android-101-how-to-create-stackview.html
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2078060&seqNum=3
- http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-stackview.html

[image]

Also this library looks decent

- https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: https://github.com/ZieIony/MaterialRecents I personally tried it and it looks promising.

Comment: This cards show up weirdly in landscape orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can always look at the official Android source code.

Check the method `startRecentsActivity()` under [packages/SystemUI](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/a6ed1b9547dcd592031a415739cc7e672c068f7c/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents/AlternateRecentsComponent.java) from the official Android source code.

It's not a very easy-to-read code, but it's definitely the best and most reliable source if you really want to mimic the official Android Lollipop animations.

Comment: karim, you're right to try to see that class but, as you said, it's not an easy code.. I think that my answer could be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a github repo with my class i hope it helps,
it's is the start i hope it helps

[Stack Cards Android](https://github.com/ElBedeawi/StackCardsAndroid/wiki)

it makes the same as your image
you can set the difference between cards, scale from card to card,
 animation duration, number of cards of course

usage easy just include the class &

```
// **Paramters definitions** :
// Activity owningActivity, RelativeLayout container, int cardHeightDP, int cardDiffDP,float cardScale, int animationDuration)
StackCards stackCards = new StackCards(yourActivity.this, cardsContainer, 100, 50, (float) 0.2, 500); 

//(Number of Cards, The Layout of the Card)
stackCards.initCards(7, R.layout.stack_card);
```