# Android: make interaction to switch between activity like Chrome's Tab Management

Tags: android, android-activity

Can anyone give me an example, how to create chrome like switching between tabs?

I want to make my application to have multiple tab. These tabs can be switched like chrome does. Must I do snapshot on `onPause`, and then on switching activity display it? Any Android Native API about this feature?

[image: Chrome's interaction on switch between tabs]

As mentioned by [jared rummler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048340/jared-rummler) https://github.com/vikramkakkar/DeckView is good enough. But, how the best way to use this. Should I get screenshot each tab (Activity)? (24/03/2017)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094666/create-ui-like-chrome-for-android

Comment: @ibrohimislam well just go through sample codes  and codes hope this will help u understand  how the DeckView works

Comment: Examine system's [`RecentsView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4f9482d/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents/views/RecentsView.java).